# Export firebase analytics into a desktop application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I have an android app connected to firebase.
What I need to do is... I need to export every real time data (eg number of users, number of users connected, etc) into another app (desktop app).
What's the best way to do that, I haven't find any video and I do not know where to start.

Someone told me to use the REST API, but the documentation really didn't help me at all.

How do I export data from firebase into a desktop app?

Thank you in advance for your time and patience

Answer (score 1):

You can create reports of the number of users in the last 30 minutes using the Google Analytics Data API. [run_realtime_report.py](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/realtime-basics#python) is an example of creating an API request.

Without writing any code, you can get an example of the API response at [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runRealtimeReport). For property request parameter, use `properties/YOUR_GA4_PROPERTY_ID`. For the request body, use the following:

```
{
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "activeUsers"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does the realtime data from this API suit your needs?